# the open interval $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not an open set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ I want to show that this is NOT an open set. I have managed to show it is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Attempt:
I need to show that at least one point is not an interior point or alternatively its complement is not closed.

I am getting stuck because I am unsure of how to write an interval in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I have guessed at $(a,b) =\{((x_{1},x_{2}),(y_{1},y_{2}): a=(x_{1},x_{2}), b=(y_{1},y_{2})\}$

Let $r>0$ and $c \in (a,b)$ then I need to consider some ball around a point in the interval and show its not contained in $(a.b)$? but I'm not too sure how to proceed as the $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is confusing me.

After comments:

$(a,b) \times \{0\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: a < x < b, y = 0\} = A$

Let $r > 0$ and $c \in A$. Then if I consider the ball centered at $c$ with radius $r$ i.e. $B(c,r)$ I need to show that this intersected with $A$ is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = (a,b) \times \{0\}$ as you said. You need to show that some $c \in A$ is not an interior point, i.e. for some $c \in A$, there does not exist $r > 0$ such that $B(c,r) \subset A$.

Hint: It turns out every point in $(a,b) \times \{0\}$ is not an interior point so consider $(0,0) \in A$. If $r > 0$, why isn't $B((0,0),r)$ contained in $A$? What point is an element of $B((0,0),r)$ that is not an element of $A$?

Drawing a picture might help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If $(0,0) \in A$ this is the same as writing $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 0<x<0, y=0\}$? So then if $r > 0, B((0,0),r)$ is not contained in $A$ as $B((0,0),r)$ contains the point $0$? drawing a picture I have a disk around the origin?

Comment: @learningmathematics Apologies, I should have specified that $(0,0)$ is referring to the point $(0,0)$, i.e. the origin (not the interval). In particular, $B((0,0),r)$ is a ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin which is exactly what you drew. Why isn't this ball you contained in $A$? The origin is in fact contained in $A$, but what's a different point in $B((0,0),r)$ that is not contained in $A$? You could try drawing the set $A$ on your diagram as well.

Comment: no problem. Maybe $(0,1)$ since in $A$ the value of $y$ is fixed as being zero?

Comment: it isn't letting me edit my previous comment, but meant to say I am viewing $(1,0)$ as a point rather than the interval.

Comment: @learningmathematics The point $(0,1)$ certainly works if $r > 1$ because then $(0,1) \in B((0,0),r)$ but $(0,1) \notin A$. But since we cannot assume $r > 1$, the point $(0,\frac{r}{2})$ would work for all $r > 0$. $(0,\frac{r}{2}) \in B((0,0),r)$ since $d((0,\frac{r}{2}),(0,0)) = \frac{r}{2} < r$ and $(0,\frac{r}{2}) \notin A$ since $\frac{r}{2} \neq 0$.

Comment: Also I just realized, I mistakenly assumed $(0,0) \in (a,b) \times \{0\}$. This is certainty not necessarily the case so apply the same argument to the point $(\frac{a+b}{2},0)$ rather than $(0,0)$. $(\frac{a+b}{2},0)$  is not an interior point because for all $r > 0$, $B((\frac{a+b}{2},0),r) \not\subset A$ since the point $(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{r}{2})$ is in $B((\frac{a+b}{2},0),r)$ but not $A$. 


The geometric point is that $(a,b) \times \{0\}$ is some interval on the $x$-axis, but it is not open because we cannot fit any open balls inside the interval.

Comment: @JLista, totally get it now thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Probably, what is confusing you is that strictly speaking $(a,b) \nsubseteq \Bbb R^2$. One usually thinks $\Bbb R$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ via the inclusion $x\mapsto (x,0)$, so what you actually need to prove is that $(a,b)\times \{0\}$ is not open.